# Octopus - multiple phase paths in the same lifecycle?

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is there a way to set up an Octopus lifecycle with options like this:

- You can deploy to DEV, but you can't promote the build from DEV
- You can deploy to QA and then promote to PROD

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [channels](https://octopus.com/docs/key-concepts/projects/channels)?

From documentation:

> Which Lifecycle to use for promoting Releases: for example, feature releases may be promoted through the testing environments, while hot-fix releases may go directly to production.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create two different projects one for deployment in Dev environment and another for QA-Prod. In our octopus setup we have two branches in TFS- Dev and main branch. A code check in into dev branch does an automatic CI release deployment into INt environment. When developers do merge from dev to main branch , an automatic release gets deployed to qa which can be later promoted to prod.  Of course another way can be Channel which Alex suggested.